# Number Representation conflict

Tags: c#

I have a situation here and I really need Help. I have a French System (with AZERTY Keyboard and Windows installed in French) However I need to input values with the English decimal system and have answers returned in that same format.  Say 5.1 * 5 = 25.5 but my system returns 25,1(Because of the OS installed ?) 
Please see code below:

```
float x = float.Parse(
                  textBox4.Text,
                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int z = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
float y = x * z;
textBox5.Text = y.ToString();
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUOVp.jpg)

Comment: Is English supposed to be your only input language?

Comment: No I wish for the code to consider both language input types of possible  as I  the francophone system 1.2 (for example) will be written 1,2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a culture parameter on the toString function     :

```
    float x = float.Parse("0.58", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int z = int.Parse("4");
    float y = x * z;
    var result = y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    //result = "2.32"
```